# When the full release will be available for Google Analytics Data API?

Tags: google-analytics

We are in the process of migrating UA to GA4 nad have a few questions. Can you please help here?

1. When the full release will be available for Data API? (Currently this is in beta version)
   Related Link: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/migration/api/reporting-ua-to-ga4
2. If we use the Data API beta version now and once the full release is available, will there be any changes to Java libraries?
3. Currently we are using UA and "google.apis.analytics.v3" API to get the data from analytics and store it in a DB. What is the equivalent GA4 API for "google.apis.analytics.v3".

Thanks,
Ramana

I tried to search for the corresponding API in Visual Studio but unable to locate the right API.

[GA4 Data API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCCaB.png)

Comment: Not sure what you may by library for Visual Studio, Visual Studio is just an IDE.  there is a .net version of the library if thats what you mean.

Comment: Yes Linda, I'm looking for .net version of the library for equivalent GA4 API.

Comment: that works with ga4 or ua analytics

Answer (score 1):

The google analytics data api is still in beta, there is no information as to when the final version will be released.

If you check the change log you will see that the api is still in development.  The libraries are updated to support any changes in the apis as they come.

[Changelog](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/changelog)